# RXJS Observables - Run a repeating function every 500ms and output results to an observable stream

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

First off - I'm new to Observables.  Coming from Python.

I am trying to acheive:

- Every 500 ms call a function to return shapes from a chart

  - shapes are returned in an array
  - I only want a filtered subset "horizontal_lines"
- Output "horizontal_lines" via an observable

The code below is functional - except it doesn't repeat.  I can't figure out timer, delay, or interval with RXJS 6.

```
// In this example the chart has 3 horizontal lines at 5,10 and 17 "prices"
// Desired output is 5 -- 10 -- 17
// When 4th line is added at 20 "price" expected output would be
// 5 -- 10 -- 17 -- 20


const test$ = new Observable<number>(observer => {
      chart
      .activeChart()
      .getAllShapes()
      .forEach((shape) => {
        if (shape.name == 'horizontal_line') {
          chart
            .activeChart()
            .getShapeById(shape.id)
            .getPoints()
            .forEach((point) => {
              observer.next(+point.price.toFixed(4));
            });
        }
      })

    }).pipe(
      delay(500),
      repeat()
```

Comment: You say you need the lines, but at the moment you're emitting the points in each line that matches the condition. What exactly do you wish to emit? Collection of all points in the line as an array? Or emit each point in each line that matches the condition individually?

Comment: Currently emit each point that matches individually.  I may switch to just an array after I am done with prototyping.  Thanks for the detailed answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `repeat` will not work unless your observable completes:

```js
const test$ = new Observable<number>(observer => {
  chart
    .activeChart()
    .getAllShapes()
    .forEach((shape) => {
      if (shape.name == 'horizontal_line') {
        chart
          .activeChart()
          .getShapeById(shape.id)
          .getPoints()
          .forEach((point) => {
            observer.next(+point.price.toFixed(4));
          });
      }
    })

  observer.complete(); // <-- Complete observable after all emissions
}).pipe(
  delay(500),
  repeat()
);
```

Comment: This one line fixed the problem!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the setTimeout function to repeat your code instead of an observable.

Here is an example of doing so.

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy {

    Alive = true

    ngOnInit(){
        this.repeating_function()
        
    }
    ngOnDestroy(){
        this.Alive = false
    }

    repeating_function(){
        // some code

        //repeat the function every 500 ms while the component is active
        if (this.Alive){
            setTimeout(() => {this.repeating_function()}, 500);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Run a repeating function every 500ms and output results to an observable stream

I think the simplest way to do this it to use [`interval`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/interval) (*or [`timer`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/timer) if you need to emit immediately*)  to create a stream of emissions every 500ms, then simply map the emission to your function's return value:

```js
test$ = interval(500).pipe(
    map(() => theFunction())
);
```

Here is a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66481840?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) of this simple example.  Obviously, you would make the function do whatever you need it to do :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you've tried so far with RxJS `timer` and `interval`. You could use `timer` and map to the required data using the `map` operator. You could then use `Array#map` with `Array#filter` to transform the data as per the requirement.

```js
timer(0, 500).pipe(   // <-- emit immediately and after every 500ms thereafter
  map(_ => 
    chart
      .activeChart()
      .getAllShapes()
      .map(shape => {
        if (shape.name === 'horizontal_line')
          return shape.getPoints()
      })
      .filter((points) => !!points)  // <-- filter `undefined` from previous step
  )
).subscribe({
  next: points => {
    /* output:
      [
        [ <collection of points from line 5> ],
        [ <collection of points from line 10> ],
        [ <collection of points from line 17> ],
        ...
      ]
    */
  }
});
```

If for whatever reason you wish to combines all the points in a single array and emit them continuously to the subscription, you'd need to use `swithcMap` operator with RxJS `from` function.

```js
timer(0, 500).pipe(
  map(_ => 
    chart
      .activeChart()
      .getAllShapes()
      .map(shape => {
        if (shape.name === 'horizontal_line')
          return shape.getPoints()
      })
      .filter((points) => !!points)  // <-- filter `undefined` from previous step
  ),
  switchMap(pointsColl => {
    return from(pointsColl.flat())
  })
).subscribe({
  next: points => {
    /* output:
      point 1 from line 5
      point 2 from line 5
      ...
    */
  }
});
```

If you instead need to emit the collection of all the points as a single array, you'd need to use `of` function instead of `from`.

```js
// <repeat from above>
  switchMap(pointsColl => {
    return of(pointsColl.flat())
  })
).subscribe({
  next: points => {
    /* output:
      [ <collection of points from line 5, 10 and 17> ]
    */
  }
});
```